# Remote Desktop Connection Data Usage

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

Does anyone know how much data it uses when I use Windows Remote Desktop Connection for an hour for normal office uses?

I'm asking because I need to connect to a computer remotely and I have to pay for the amount of data I use. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"Hourly bandwidth consumption at rates like these can vary from ~12M to 3.4G+. Unless you are watching video over RDP, the higher end of the ladder is highly unlikely. For normal activity at 1024x768 resolution with standard settings I'd estimate about ~25M per hour."* (c) John T

Similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/43797/microsoft-remote-desktop-bandwidth-usage

Comment: This seems fairly spot on based on what we see. For 1 user using basic apps over terminal servers, we're seeing approx 5Kbps usage. In other words, about the same as a dial-up connection or a VoIP phone call.